# Using a public git project with google collab

Tags: github, google-colaboratory

I'm facing an issue while trying to access files from my GitHub repository within a Google Colab notebook. Here are the steps I followed:
Cloned the GitHub repository with the command:

https://github.com/my_user_name/project_name

Now I can see all the files on the left side of the notebook, when I run the main of the project on pycharm everything works.

However, when I attempt to access the files in the repository, I encounter an error. I'm unsure about the correct way to access these files and utilize them within the Colab notebook. Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your help!